# Is it possible to change the password for a WiFi network when it is not in range?

Tags: wi-fi, password

Long-pressing on a WiFi network that is in range brings up a menu that includes "Modify network", which can be used to change the password for the network. Networks that are not in range do not show up on this screen.

Under "Saved networks", long-pressing is the same a simple press. This brings only the options "Forget" and "Done".

Is it possible to modify the password for a WiFi network that is not in range? Must it appear under current WiFi networks?

I am trying to do this on both unrooted Android 5.1 and 6.0 devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete it ('Forget') and create it new again, here you can define the password. Write down the SSID (Routers name) and encryption way (e.g. WPA) before you delete it ;)

Without root you cannot view or edit the /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf file (this is the path on Android CM13), where the network configs are saved. That means ssid, passwords (psk) etc.

Answer (score 0):

1.if you are looking to change the main router common authentication password...you cant ..has to be in range or LAN(via PC)

2.if you want to change the password on the device of the network to comply with the newly changed password of the router ....you can choose to modify network ...or simply forget it and re-connect ...

Comment: I am trying to do 2. There is no modify network when the network is not in range.

Comment: okay ...so you need it to be in range to be able to modify the network ....

Comment: or what you can do is ....use a root explorer ...head to the root directory....data ...wpa supplicant ....edit ...and find your network and type in the new password ....NOTE : im on lollipop so its that directory ...not sure if itll be different for your device ....give it a search